# Redirecting output of Google Dataproc query into a text file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a requirement where I need the output of Google Dataproc in a text file.

For example, I have below query:

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster=$CLUSTER --region=$REGION \
    --execute="select count(*) from db.table;"
```

I just need the information of record count in the flat file.

I am using something like below (redirection operator). However, it gives me the entire data which gets printed in console.

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster=$CLUSTER --region=$REGION \
    --execute="select count(*) from db.table;" > text.csv
```

Desired output for me would be:

```
724
```

where `724` is the total number of records in my table.

**Workaround Solution:**

gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster=$CLUSTER --region=$REGION \
    --execute="select count(*) from db.table;" &> text.csv

Use **"&"** before redirection. It will redirect the whole output to test.csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by the Dataproc Jobs API. You probably will have to do some output parsing before the redirecting. I filed a feature request to separate stdout and stderr in the Jobs API output. Thanks for the feedback.